# Clicking Link is not opening the PWA on iOS

Tags: php, iphone, progressive-web-apps

I have made PWA which sends users text messages with the links to open, the links are opening in PWA while using the Android but on iOS the link gets opened in safari instead of installed PWA. Any idea why that happens or how to resolve the issue?

This is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Worship Support Network",
  "short_name": "WSN",
  "description": "Worship Support Network Portals",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "theme_color": "#0077b5",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/wsn_icon_white-on-blue.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/assets/images/wsn_icon_white-on-blue.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```